# Split large txt file into smaller one, with awk

Tags: awk, split

Currently I have 1.2GB of file, which are consist of 86 columns, and approx. 230+ million rows.

It's look like this :

```
Column1     2   3       4       5           6       ... 86
50000004    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 1
50000003    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 2
50000005    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 5
50000012    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 13
50000016    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 11
...
```

I just posted first some columns - it's too many to write in this posting.

and there is no header - so first rows data is {50000004, 01, ... 1}.

Last Column, which I want to split by that column, is 86th.

So It should be split like this :

```
1.txt
50000004    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 1

2.txt
50000003    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 2

5.txt
50000005    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 5

13.txt
50000012    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 13

11.txt
50000016    01  000000  0010    HS1281      1281    ... 11
```

**Problem**

In Excel PowerQuery, It is indeed Column 86 - There is a lot of spaces / empty between column, but it is splited by tabs.

I'm currently using Windows, so my awk is look like this :

```
awk "BEGIN { OFS = \""\t\"" } { print > $86 \"".txt\""}" filename
```

But It returns no result - just 1 file with original size.

**Question**

1. It seems awk saw "space" is empty column, so they remove it entirely if whole rows are
   empty. Am I correct?
2. I do some search and found some code, which returns last column of file - it shows 55. It doesn't match with 86 columns, which I'm sure of it, because source data have 86 rows.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If there is no header in your real data then don't show a header in your sample input

Comment: Regarding "It seems awk saw "space" is empty column, so they remove it entirely if whole rows are empty. Am I correct?" - it's not clear what you mean by that or how it relates to your question. In particular which line of your sample input would exhibit that problem?

Comment: Save your awk script in a file and execute it as `awk -f scriptfile.txt` to avoid Windows quoting nightmare, at least while working on a solution. You can always move it to the command line and mangle the quotes, etc. later if you like.

Comment: how many distinct values are in the 86th column? when copying lines to new files do you need to maintain the lines in the same order as they appear in the source file?  do you have 1.25 GB of free disk or memory availaible in your system? if the number of unique value is large there's a good chance an `awk` solution will be quite slow if it needs to open/close/reopen a lot of file descriptors ... so pre-sorting the file would be of benefit but then we need to look at how much memory and/or disk space is available to hold a sorted copy of the file

Comment: is the file already sorted by a column(s) and if so which column(s)? this would be of benefit if we need to resort the file and maintain the ordering of lines (per unique value in Column86)

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to feel stupid.

> awk "BEGIN{ FS=""\t"" };{ print > $86 "".txt"" }" filename

OFS is for output - If you want for input, use "FS", not "OFS".